# How can i add these sentences to a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a directory of files entitled `45-1.txt` `1-17.txt` etc.. basically they're 2 numbers seperated by a '-' with .txt at the end. 
And i have a dataset that looks like this but has thousands of lines:

```
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2112.0,545.0,2136.0,554.0
values/test/45/blueprint-1.png,112.0,45.0,36.0,654.0
```

The values that i care about in these lines are the first 2 numbers of each line, so `10-0`, `10-0`,`45-1` etc..
what i want to do is to copy the lines that have the 2 numbers let's say 10-0 as a part of the name of 1 of the previous files, in this example 45-1 should be copied.

My approach:

```
import os,csv,re

my_dict = {}
source_dir = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/testing_txts/'

for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = ''
# print(my_dict)

with open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for key in my_dict:
      for filename, *numbers in reader:
          k1, k2 = re.findall(r'\d+', filename)
          k3,k4 = re.findall(r'\d+', key)
          if k3 == k1 and k2 == k4:
              my_dict[key].append(filename)
```

To explain what i did a bit, i read all the name files in my directory and made them keys in a dictionary, then will read my file line by line for a specific key, if i find a similar line exists i will append the entire line to the specific dictionary key so assuming we have in the first directory `25-1.txt` , `45-1.txt` and `1-0.txt`,  and in the other file i have :

```
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2089.0,545.0,2100.0,546.0
values/test/10/blueprint-0.png,2112.0,545.0,2136.0,554.0
values/test/45/blueprint-1.png,112.0,45.0,36.0,654.0
values/test/45/blueprint-1.png,2.0,5.0,6.0,54.0
```

the end result will be 3 keys only 45-1 having elements in it and the elements are `values/test/45/blueprint-1.png,112.0,45.0,36.0,654.0` and `values/test/45/blueprint-1.png,2.0,5.0,6.0,54.0` (list of elements) the issue that i had with my code above is that i can't append the full sentence properly and get my keys with elements i get the error can't use append with strings and when i used `my_dict[key] =filename` to test knowing that it wrong and overwrites, only my first key had any element in it the rest were empty knowing they should exist as well.

**Edit:**
After fixing a list issue after a helpful answer and i did some quick adjustments my code became:

```
import os,csv,re

my_dict = {}
source_dir = '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/testing_txts/'

for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = []
# print(my_dict)

with open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for key in my_dict:
      for filename in reader:
          print(filename)
          k = []
          k.append(re.findall(r'\d+', str(filename)))
          k1,k2 = k[0][0],k[0][1]
          k3,k4 = re.findall(r'\d+', key)
          if k3 == k1 and k2 == k4:
              my_dict[key].append(filename)

print(my_dict)
```

However my main issue of not every key is getting the elements persists as many keys stay empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = ''
```

You have initialized your my_dict values to be string. Hence when you use append it will create `AttributeError`. Because you can't append to a string

**Approach 1** is to mention the values are a list and then join them as a string when reading it. `append` will not throw an error in this case

```
for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = []
```

**Approach 2** is to use string concatenation

```
my_dict[key] += filename
```

**Issue 2**

I am not really sure but guessing that it might be because of the looping over the dict.

```
with open('/home/ubuntu/Desktop/EAST/ground_truth.txt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for filename in reader:
     print(filename)
     k1,k2 = re.findall(r'\d+', str(filename)
     my_dict[k1+"-"+k2].append(filename)
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks can't believe i didn't notice that but it doesn't solve my second issue of only the first key having elements.

Comment: I don't exactly get your 2nd issue. can you separate the two issues in the question. Also what is the output you are expecting and what are you getting

Comment: Regarding the second issue, let's assume i have 10 keys and all of these 10 keys should have sentences in them(elements), i am getting elements in only, let's say 6 for no apparent reason, as i did the debugging and printed the keys after `for key in my_dict:` all the keys are there so it doesn't make sense why it would work normally for the first elements in the dictionary and completely nothing for the rest.

Comment: Updated with a modified code try it out and let me know if it works

Comment: It didn't i'll accept your answer still for helping me in the first part and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,csv,re

my_dict = {}
source_dir = 'source'

for element in os.listdir(source_dir):
    my_dict[element] = []
# print(my_dict)

with open('readme.txt') as f:
    reader = f.readlines()

    for key in my_dict:
        for line in reader:
            k1= re.findall(r'\d+', line)
            k1 = k1[0] + k1[1]
            key_stripped = key.replace('-','').replace('.txt', '')
            if k1 == key_stripped:
                my_dict[key].append(line)

print(my_dict)
```